# How does windows associate a device with a driver?

Tags: windows, operating-system, driver

Currently I study the Microsoft Documentation about drivers.

The are plenty of examples in the documentaion but there is something that is not very clear. When you develope a driver for a piece of hardware you **must set an entry point** and and a **callback for when the device is pluged in**, but you dont have to specify an identifier for your device.

**How does Windows know that this specific driver is for my hardware?**

**Does the INF files that are generated with the .sys file contain that information?**